# Compiling Apache on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, windows-vista, compilation

I'd like to custom compile Apache for my Windows (Vista) machine. Do I need a special compiler for this, and how do I know if I already have a compiler (I have eclipse, but not sure if that's suitable).

Also, all I can find is linux tutorials. How would one get this done on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/win_compiling.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm still wondering about the compiler. Do I still need a special compiler. I don't want to download Microsoft Visual C++ just for this since I don't use MS Visual C++ at all.